# Does React use Redux or Flux by default?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, flux, tsx

When I create a new react app with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` what kind of software architecture does it have by default (MVC, Redux or Flux)? I read all the differences and I got confused a little bit, so I would like to know what do I get by default and stick to it, so that I get a better understanding on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

React does not provide any state management library like Redux or Flux natively or when you create a react app with CLI.

**React only provide support for context API natively.**

You can install supporting packages and libraries as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of features that come out of the box create-react-app.

You can run a single command and get a brand new React application that comes with:

- A recommended starting folder structure
- A solid build setup with webpack and Babel (that you don't have to worry about setting up)
- Scripts to run our React application
- Extensibility

**Redux** is a predictable state container designed to help you write JavaScript apps that behave consistently across client, server, and native environments and are easy to test. While it's mostly used as a state management tool with React, you can use it with any other JavaScript framework or library. React does not support **Redux** by default, you have to integrate that.

**React** by default support ContextAPI. Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.